# Snapshot pending transactions address strike through line

Tags: transaction, wallet, tangle, pending, snapshot

Hi I have got bit of issue as I have got balance in my seed now as we all know the snapshot happening on 28 jan 2018 was reading article where is says any pending transactions will be wiped out or shall we delete from tangle now as my address says pending what will happen to my Balance.
I was checking my addresses one of the address is got line throughout as in pic [image: wallet]

Comment: Is your pending transaction a re-attachment of another confirmed transaction ?

Comment: @ben75 what do u mean by that as I got all transactions in wallet is pending but my balance I can see there

Comment: Addresses get striked out when they already have been spend from, that shouldn't play any role here.What you need to look for is whether you have unconfirmed transactions in 'Transfers' that also weren't confirmed by reattachments.

Comment: @cmpn when u say Unconfirmed that means pending as all my transactions attachment says pending I m bit worried what will happen if I can’t get them confirmed plz help

Comment: @Rishab Address attachments do not matter. Only transactions that transfer coins should be confirmed before the snapshot. Simply spoken: if every coin transfer you made was successful you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score -1):

Now if you reattache and you will get your balance 
Thanks

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/899)